# Angular2 - Add an Attribute

Tags: css, angular

I have below Angular2 code below

```
        <ngx-datatable-column prop="id" name="ID">
            <template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-row="row" let-value="value">
                <a [routerLink]="['/devicedtls',row.id]">{{row.id}}</a>
            </template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
```

Then Trying to add  `attr.data-div="ID Test"` inside `<template......`

```
        <ngx-datatable-column prop="id" name="ID">
            <template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-row="row" let-value="value" attr.data-div="ID Test">
                <a [routerLink]="['/devicedtls',row.id]">{{row.id}}</a>
            </template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
```

In CSS, I want to call a value of `attr.data-div` by

```
 .datatable .datatable-body .datatable-body-cell:before {
        content: attr(data-div)": ";
    }
```

When I view it in a browser, ": " is showing, but the value of `data-div` doesn't show.

What is wrong, or missing here?  Please give a hand.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't add attributes to template. Template is used a "block" with inner content and list of let-var (variables) to build the grid. You can make reach content inside template if you need.

You can look at "Angular Grids Destructuring" https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/angular-grids-destructuring-7488757e06a1 blog that describes the template mechanism in details.

Comment: Hi Julia, Thank you so much for your explanation! As you have mentioned `You can make reach content inside template`, I wonder how to create a content and can I call the value's content by .CSS?